# I keep crashing with Inserting a record using OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, oledb

```
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tickets (ProblemIncidentDate, ProblemIncidentTime, user, StateTagNumber, ProblemType, ProblemDescription, ProblemStatus) VALUES (@ProblemDate,@ProblemTime,@userIDNumber,@StateTag,@ProblemType,@ProblemDescription,@ProblemStatus)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProblemDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = labelProblemDate.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProblemTime", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = labelProblemTime.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userIDNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(userID.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StateTag", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxStateTagNumber.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProblemType", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBoxProblemType.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProblemDescription", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxProblemDescription.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProblemStatus", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Open";            
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          //At this line exception is generating 
        conn.Close();
```

My database is a Microsoft Access 2007

Here are the field types

```
ID                  AutoNumber
ProblemIncidentDate Date/Time
ProblemIncidentTime Date/Time
user                Number
StateTagNumber      Text
ProblemType         Text
ProblemDescription  Memo
ProblemResolution   Memo
ProblemStatus       Text
```

I can't figure out why it's crashing

The console message says

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: It helps when you post an error.  Normally error message contain hints as to what the problem is.

Comment: Try putting brackets around `[user]`, it might be keyword.  Also, you are passing strings into your Integer and DateTime fields.

Comment: Lars - you're right. Putting the [] around user solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the correct datatypes like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProblemDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(labelProblemDate.Text.Trim());

cmd.Parameters.Add("@userIDNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.Int32(userID.ToString());
```

Comment: Must be TimeSpan. Check the list on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

Comment: Even with fixing the datatypes, I am still crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Converted from my comment:

> Try putting brackets around [user], it might be keyword.  Also, you are passing strings into your Integer and DateTime fields.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with different OleDb providers and found that some do NOT like named parameters, and instead, just use a "?" as a place-holder for the parameter.  Just note that the parameters need to be added in the same sequence as the insert (just like you have), so try changing to..

```
insert into YourTable( fld1, fld2, fld3 ) values ( ?, ?, ? )
```